# How to use hashmap or enumMap with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, enum-map

I want to use EnumMap with Thymeleaf.

The enum map:

`Map<MyEnum, Integer> enumMap = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);`

This may be HashMap instead of EnumMap.

My enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ENUMKEY1("a"),
    ENUMKEY2("b"),
    ENUMKEY3("c");

    private final String value;

    CrawlerStatusType(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

My Controller return this model:

```
...
model.addAttribute("enumMap", enumMap);
...
```

My script:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*[+             
         var enumMap = [[${enumMap}]];
         +]*/

         ...
    });
</script>
```

But If I run it, the enumMap is seen as follow:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

         var enumMap = {{'$type':'MyEnum','$name':'a'}:7,{'$type':'MyEnum','$name':'b'}:2,{'$type':'MyEnum','$name':'c'}:7};

       ...
    });
```

I want to be as follow:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

         var enumMap = {'a':7,'b':2,'c':7};

       ...
    });
```

How to do it?

Comment: use some loop to construct the javascript?

Comment: There is an error on browser console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {...